# Chart in Angular not displayed until windows resize

Tags: angular, chart.js, angular9, chartjs-2.6.0

If there any solution to this issue please let me know.
I still new to using the chart.js and Angular. when I try to pull the graph datasets using API, graph seems hidden until I change the window size. I dont know if Im doig wrong or it is problem in the chart.js module. Please help, thank you.

[Before resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzHzy.png)

[After resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwjD8.png)

[HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWOT8.png)

[TS typescript code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTuuJ.png)

Comment: Please share the code in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mahdhg?file=src/app/app.module.ts @DeepuReghunath but got some error since I dont know how to call json data in certain id in service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a reason why you're seeing that chart after resize because you're nesting your API calls and **angular change-detection** doesn't work well with nested functions. There're 2 solutions to this problem.

1. You can flatten your API calls and remove nesting or
2. you can use changeDetectorRef to trigger the change detection by

   ```
   constructor(
             private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef

   ) {}
   ```

   use the below statement after your calculation is finished.

   this.cdr.markForCheck();

I'd advise you to go for the first option.

Comment: Thank you. I try the to flatten my API and its working. Thank you! :D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can try it with setTimeout. Because while the the chart rendering, the container has no size